# Is there a standard for sizing a web page with CSS

Tags: css, asp.net, standards

I'm only just now learning anything about CSS through my ASP.net class and I'm wondering if there is a standard for making web sites fit all resolutions.

My textbook simply states "This way, the site fits nicely on screens with a size of 1024 x 768 pixels, a common screen size for many of today’s computers, without being squeezed between the Windows borders. Systems with bigger screens
simply center the site in the available space." -Beginning ASP.NET 4.5 in C# and VB by Imar Spaanjaars

Though I feel this works, I also feel like it's not the standard practice when using CSS.

Any information would be great, as I'm very new to CSS, ASP.Net, and HTML in general.

Comment: Was your textbook written last century?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Responsive_web_design

Comment: Key phrases for you to look up: Responsive Design, Media Queries, Device Viewports

Comment: @Quentin It's copyright is 2013 and it seems to cover HTML5 pretty heavily. I did think it seemed odd too.

Comment: @JackBracken Thanks, this should give me a good starting point!

Comment: @Fuzzyketchup — Sounds like a badly updated edition of something written a long, long time ago.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are such things as standard page sizes, such as 800x600, 1024x768, and 1280x1024, and different camps have their opinions; but more recent design theories are focusing on responsive design because of the myriad different sizes of screens.

You should design with a few sizes in mind but then make sure the designs look good on as many devices as possible.  If you don't have dozens of different screen sizes to work with, the services like the link below can help you check your site using different virtual screen sizes:

http://quirktools.com/screenfly/

Comment: I do think that responsive web design is the answer to my question, so I thank you, and the other people who answered.

Edit: One question I do have about quirktools is if it's able to be connected to a Visual Studio website that hasn't been put on a domain yet.

Answer (score 0):

For general use case, you can use percentage to adapt your content to the screen size. For example,

```
<style>
div {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 80px auto;
  padding: 25px;
  background-color: #ccc;
}
</style>
<div>Hi!</div>
```

will display a div which will adapt itself depending of the size of the screen (try resize your window) because of the `width: 80%;`.

If you want to change CSS rules depending of the size of the screen (technic called "responsive design") then you should use the `@media query` keywords. See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries)